# SumIF in SQL Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hello I am a beginner in VBA/SQL.    I have 2 tables [Broker] and [OPT]. [Broker] have 2 fields `BRKR_CODE, Status` and [OPT] Have 5 fields `BRKR1, BRKR2, Date, COM_BRK1, COM_BRKR2`

`OPT.BRKR1` and `OPT.BRKR2` are linked to `Broker.BRKR_CODE` and can be equal.

I want to write this query.... If `Broker.Status="Active"` then Select `Broker.BRKR_CODE`
and then for each `Broker.BRKR_CODE` (for example "CB") do the Sum of `OPT.COM_BRKR1` when `OPT.BRKR1="CB"` + Sum of `OPT.COM_BRKR2` when `OPT.BRKR2="CB"`

I wrote this code.... but it doesnot work at all... as I said I am a newbie...

```
    SELECT IIF(Broker.Status="Active",Broker.BRKR_CODE), Sum(OPT.COM_BRKR1)+ Sum(OPT.COM_BRKR2) AS OPT_Tot

FROM Broker INNER JOIN OPT ON (Broker.BRKR_CODE = OPT.BRKR2) AND (Broker.BRKR_CODE = OPT.BRKR1)

GROUP BY Broker.BRKR_CODE;
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to change two things in your query.  The first is to move the condition to the `where` clause.  You seem to only want "Active" things.  The second is to change the `AND` in the `on` clause to `OR`.  You want matches on either code.

```
SELECT Broker.BRKR_CODE,
       Sum(OPT.COM_BRKR1)+ Sum(OPT.COM_BRKR2) AS OPT_Tot
FROM Broker INNER JOIN
     OPT
     ON (Broker.BRKR_CODE = OPT.BRKR2) OR (Broker.BRKR_CODE = OPT.BRKR1)
WHERE Broker.Status = "Active"
GROUP BY Broker.BRKR_CODE;
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your answer... this works perfectly... I have another question.... I have another table named [TRS] that has the same features... I tried to writes 2 times the sames code just changing `OPT` by `TRS` but this didn't work... I want to have 2 columns `OPT_Tot` and `TRS_Tot`

Comment: @sharkantipav . . . You should post another question (and you can reference this one).  It helps to have sample data and desired output as well.

Comment: Here is the next question  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538867/sumif-access-multiple-tables)  thanks