# SumIF Access - Multiple tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am following the question I asked here: [SumIF in SQL Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22535665/sumif-in-sql-access)

I have 3 tables [Broker] , [OPT], [TRS]. [Broker] have 2 fields `BRKR_CODE, Status` and [OPT] and [TRS] Have 5 same fields `BRKR1, BRKR2, Date, COM_BRK1, COM_BRKR2`

`OPT.BRKR1`, `OPT.BRKR2`, `TRS.BRKR1`, `TRS.BRKR2` are linked to `Broker.BRKR_CODE` and can be equal.

I want to write this query.... If `Broker.Status="Active"` then Select `Broker.BRKR_CODE`
and then for each `Broker.BRKR_CODE` (for example "CB") do the Sum of `OPT.COM_BRKR1` when `OPT.BRKR1="CB"` + Sum of `OPT.COM_BRKR2` when `OPT.BRKR2="CB"`  and  do the Sum of `TRS.COM_BRKR1` when `TRS.BRKR1="CB"` + Sum of `TRS.COM_BRKR2` when `TRS.BRKR2="CB"`

I wrote this code using the answer I got in the previous question... but still have syntax issue... basically I want to have an array with 3 column `BRKR_CODE`, `OPT_Tot`, `TRS_Tot`

```
SELECT Broker.BRKR_CODE,
       Sum(OPT.COM_BRKR1)+ Sum(OPT.COM_BRKR2) AS OPT_Tot,
       Sum(TRS.COM_BRKR1)+ Sum(TRS.COM_BRKR2) AS TRS_Tot
FROM Broker 
     INNER JOIN  OPT
     ON (Broker.BRKR_CODE = OPT.BRKR2) OR (Broker.BRKR_CODE = OPT.BRKR1)
      INNER JOIN  TRS
     ON (Broker.BRKR_CODE = TRS.BRKR2) OR (Broker.BRKR_CODE = TRS.BRKR1)
WHERE Broker.Status = "Active"
GROUP BY Broker.BRKR_CODE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to make this query in the designer (just to get the base joins right). You'll see Access does some different stuff with parentheses that other SQL engines don't do.

You need to wrap each set of joins in parentheses

```
SELECT Broker.BRKR_CODE,
       Sum(OPT.COM_BRKR1)+ Sum(OPT.COM_BRKR2) AS OPT_Tot,
       Sum(TRS.COM_BRKR1)+ Sum(TRS.COM_BRKR2) AS TRS_Tot
FROM (Broker 
     INNER JOIN  OPT
     ON (Broker.BRKR_CODE = OPT.BRKR2) OR (Broker.BRKR_CODE = OPT.BRKR1))
      INNER JOIN  TRS
     ON (Broker.BRKR_CODE = TRS.BRKR2) OR (Broker.BRKR_CODE = TRS.BRKR1)
WHERE Broker.Status = "Active"
GROUP BY Broker.BRKR_CODE
```

Comment: This works well but very very slow... Any idea to make it quicker... read about indexes but don't really know how to set up

Comment: How slow is slow? How many records are in each table? how many records are in the final result set? What's the deal with the `BRKR1` and `BRKR2` columns? I'd think making a table structure where you don't join using an `OR` would help.